# How to change partition type id without formatting?

Tags: partition, fdisk, gparted, testdisk

How to change my partition type id from 83 to 8e without formatting and losing data?

Answer (score 17):

Run `fdisk` on the appropriate disk, for example

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

Press <kbd>t</kbd> to change the type of a partition. If there are several, you will be asked which one you want to change:

```
Partition number (1,2, default 2):
```

If there’s only one, `fdisk` will tell you it’s automatically selecting it:

```
Selected partition 1
```

Once the partition is selected, `fdisk` will ask what type you want:

```
Partition type (type L to list all types):
```

Enter `8e` here. Press <kbd>p</kbd> to check the result, then <kbd>w</kbd> to write it to disk if the changes are OK or <kbd>q</kbd> to quit without saving.

This won’t touch the contents of the partition, you won’t lose any data. It also won’t set LVM up, if that’s what you’re really after.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo sfdisk --part-type <dev> <part_no> <part_id>
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add some explanations on the tool itself and its options when used to solve the OP's problem.